# Interbase partitioning

Tags: sql, database, partition, interbase

Is there a way to partition a table by range, hash or list like we do in MySQL?
I've look on many forums and such sites and haven't found anything.

Well, hope you can help me with this thing that's driving me mad.

Comment: You should include input data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why someone downvoted your question. It seems to be that you need to make your own stored procedures to get the work done. There's no info at all, it's a shame, i need this information too.